# Save/delete Django model after celery task

Tags: python, django, asynchronous, celery, django-celery

All my Django models depends on the result of a third party API. To guarantee that the HTTP calls finish successfully I created a set of celery tasks to save/delete any models to chain them. In general those look something like:

```
@shared_task
def create(model_data_dict, ModelClass):
    new_model = ModelClass(**model_data_dict)
    new_model.save()
```

Combined with the HTTP calls the celery task chain is something like

```
from celery import chain

from model_tasks import create

def create_a_model(model_data_dict):
    chain(
        call_http_api.s(model_data_dict) |
        # Use the result from the HTTP API to create the model
        create.s(AModelClass)
    )
```

Now I was wandering if there is a more Django friendly approach on this?, (something more out-of-the-box maybe). I've checked the [Django on-commit transaction](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/db/transactions/#performing-actions-after-commit), but those seem to be for a use case where the result of the task is not important.

Comment: better how? what shortcomings do you see with the current solution?

Comment: From my experience with Django, it seems like there was always something that solved my problem in a more elegant way. I was curious if that also happened here.

NOTE: I'll update my question to clarify that.